# readline() is skipping lines in source file

Tags: python, readline, accumulator

I have a .txt file that I created with multiple lines.

When I run a for loop, with a count accumulator, it skips lines.

It skips the top line, and starts with the second, prints the fourth, the sixth, etc.

What is it I'm missing?

```
def main():
    # Open file line_numbers.txt
    data_file = open('line_numbers.txt', 'r')

    # initialize accumulatior
    count = 1
      

    # Read all lines in data_file
    for line in data_file:
        # Get the data from the file
        line = data_file.readline()

        # Display data retrieved
        print(count, ": ", line)

        # add to count sequence
        count += 1
```

Comment: I think @Shelhammer nailed it.  I guess it's unobvious that "in" does a read.   Well, it does.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try removing the "line=data_file.readline()" altogether? I suspect the "for line in data_file:" is also a readline operation.

Comment: Now its not skipping, but its counting blank lines on the output? so instead of 1-5, its returning 1 - 11

Answer (score 11):

You for loop is iterating over the data_file and your readline() is competing with it. Erase the `line = data_file.readline()` line of your code for this result:

```
# Read all lines in data_file
count = 1
for line in data_file:
    # Display data retrieved
    print(count, ": ", line)

    # add to count sequence
    count += 1
```

Answer (score 4):

`for line in data_file` already gets the text of each line for you - the subsequent call to readline then gets the *following* line. In other words, removing the call to readline will do what you want. At the same time, you don't need to keep track of an accumulator variable yourself - python has a built-in way of doing this using `enumerate` - in other words:

```
data_file = open('line_numbers.txt', 'r')
for count, line in enumerate(data_file):
    ...
```

Comment: And for the OP's edification, let's improve that even more better by using `with open('line_numbers.txt') as data_file:`

Comment: +1 indeed for enumerate(). Don't forget it numbers from zero, so when printing for human consumption you often want to add one to the count. Most people are more comfortable with 1-based numbering.

Comment: Thank you guys.  I'm in a class, thats teaching from "basics" but I will definitely put this in my notes!!